# GXT 4.0.1 Application build issue with java 6

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have implemented application with GWT 2.7 & GXT 4.0.1.Building application with java 7 & 8 is working file but it is failing with java6 & getting the below error.

```
Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'
[INFO]          Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.data.Data'
[INFO]             Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.core.Core'
[INFO]                [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
[INFO] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sencha/gxt/core/rebind/XTemplatesGenerator : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GXT 4.0.1 does not support Java 1.6. Take a look here: http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/getting_started/Versions.html

Comment: Document mentioned Its supports for compiling and running but not supports for debug.

GXT 4.0 requires the Java 1.7 although it can use the Java 1.6 compiler to compile the classes. But when using Java 1.6 compiler the SDM debug launcher will have to use Java 1.7. This means you can compile the applicaiton using Java 1.6 and deploy on Java 1.6 web servers. Keep in mind that when using Java 1.6 that you will have to use the Java 1.6 specification compliance.
GWT 2.8.0 notes